# How can we use Pytorch Autograd for sequence optimization (in a for loop)?

Tags: python, optimization, deep-learning, pytorch, autograd

I want to optimize a sequence in a for loop using Pytorch Autograd. I am using **LBFGS**.

```
loss = 0.0
for i in range(10):
     x = f(x,z[i])
     loss = loss + mse_loss(x,x_GT)
```

Say the sequence length is 10. I want to **optimize `x` as well as `z`(z is a tensor array)**, **these are learnable parameters.**  Note the `x` will be updated in the loop.

`x_GT` is ground truth data.

To run this, I have to open:

```
loss.backward(retain_graph=True)
```

Is there a better way to do so (To make it run faster)?

Comment: If `x` and `z` are your learned parameters, what is your model input? "*To run this, I have to open:*", why so? Do you get an error while running your code?

Comment: Sorry, it should be loss.backward(retain_graph=True).

Comment: Please add details to your question: if `x` and `z` are your learned parameters, what is your model's input? How is `loss` being defined?

Comment: I have provided an answer, see below.

Answer (score 1):

The code you provided is actually perfectly fine:

```
loss = torch.zeros(1)
for i in range(10):
     x = f(x, z[i])
     loss += mse_loss(x, x_GT)
```

It will accumulate the loss over the loop steps. The backward pass only needs to be called once, though, so you are **not required** to retain the graph on it:

```
>>> loss.backward()
```

I don't believe *not* retaining the graph will make your code run any faster. It only adds to the memory load since it has to save all activations on the graph, expecting a second backward pass to come.